# Validate SELECT-OPTIONS values on a screen?

Tags: abap, dynpro

In this event I am throwing message

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_vari.
  CLEAR g_variant.
  PERFORM set_variant.

  IF g_msg IS NOT INITIAL.
    MESSAGE g_msg TYPE 'S' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
  ENDIF.**
```

And here I have two select option and a parameter in different block.

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON BLOCK group.
  CLEAR g_msg.
  IF s_prg IS INITIAL AND s_wbs IS INITIAL.
    CONCATENATE g_msg  text-002 INTO g_msg SEPARATED BY space.
  ELSEIF s_prg IS NOT INITIAL AND s_wbs IS NOT INITIAL.
    CONCATENATE g_msg  text-003 INTO g_msg SEPARATED BY space.
  ENDIF.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_vari.
  CLEAR: g_esito.
  PERFORM check_vari CHANGING g_esito
                              g_msg
                              g_variant.
```

I would like to see the message of the parameter p_vari if the select options are valued.
I would not like to see the message when I use the select option match code.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (your code doesn't compile), explain what "don't work correctly" means i.e. [what you expect and what it does currently, and what you have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should read about the [order of selection-screen events](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_47x200/helpdata/en/56/1eb6c705ad11d2952f0000e8353423/content.htm?no_cache=true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simply `at-selection-screen` statement to validate parameters and throw messages if necessary. it should work, but unfortunately I do not have the knowledge to explain why.